# Fallo generando números aleatorios: algunos números son más comunes que otros

Tags: c++, random

Estoy haciendo pruebas de generación de números aleatorios con [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) pero no están dando los resultados esperados, este es mi programa de prueba:

```
std::srand(std::time(nullptr));

constexpr unsigned valores = 10u;
constexpr unsigned limite = 0xffffffffu;

unsigned v[valores]{};

while (!std::any_of(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [limite](auto v) { return v == limite; }))
    ++v[std::rand() % valores];

const auto total = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), .0);

std::cout << "Total: " << total;

for (const auto& valor : v)
    std::cout << valor << '\t' << valor / total << '\n';
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

> ```
> Total:    42947046200
> 4294966596    0.1000060
> 4294967012    0.1000060
> 4294966528    0.1000060
> 4294966953    0.1000060
> 4294967162    0.1000060
> 4294966644    0.1000060
> 4294966519    0.1000060
> 4294967295    0.1000060
> 4293656217    0.0999756
> 4293655274    0.0999756
> ```

Habiendo generado casi cuarenta y tres mil millones de números aleatorios entre el cero y el nueve esperaba que cada número apareciera un 10% de las veces. Pero no es así, el rango [0, 7] es más común que los números ocho y nueve.

Necesito que la distribución sea uniforme para transformarla en una distribución normal con el [método Box Muller](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Box-Muller), pero ya he podido ver que no es del todo uniforme. He hecho las mismas pruebas con varias raíces aleatorias y el resultado siempre es el mismo. ¿Por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 3):

El problema que tienes en realidad son dos problemas. El primer problema es matemático y tiene que ver con el uso del operador módulo (`%`) el segundo problema es de la función `std::rand`.

##### Problema(s)

La función [`std::rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand), devuelve números pseudoaleatorios en el rango [​`0`, [`RAND_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/RAND_MAX)], la única garantía sobre el valor de `RAND_MAX` es que será al menos 32767<sup>1</sup> yo no se recomienda su uso para la generación de números pseudoaleatorios con una mínima seriedad<sup>2</sup> ya que:

- Es dependiente de implementación.
- No da garantías de la calidad de la secuencia obtenida.

  - Puede tener poca variancia en bits bajos.
  - Las semillas pueden tener un periodo corto.

Pero aún suponiendo que `std::rand` no tuviera problema alguno, aún queda la cuestión del uso del operador módulo (`%`). Suponiendo que tu `RAND_MAX` sea 32767, en el rango [0, 32767] tienes:

- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es cero.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es uno.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es dos.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es tres.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es cuatro.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es cinco.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es seis.
- 3277 números cuyo `% 10` es siete.
- 327**6** números cuyo `% 10` es ocho.
- 327**6** números cuyo `% 10` es nueve.

Ahí tienes el motivo por el que los números ocho y nueve son menos comunes. La única manera de evitar este efecto negativo al usar el módulo contra el retorno de `std::rand` es usando un divisor exacto del valor `RAND_MAX`.

##### Solución

No uses `std::rand`, usa las utilidades de la cabecera de C++11 [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random). Usándolas en tu código de prueba:

```
constexpr unsigned valores = 10u;
constexpr unsigned limite = 0xffffffffu;

unsigned v[valores]{};

std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generador(device());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distri(0, 9);
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~          ^  ^
//               \                      \  \__ Valor máximo generado.
//                \                      \
//                 \                      \___ Valor mínimo generado.
//                  \
//                   \___ Distribución uniforme.

while (!std::any_of(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [limite](auto v) { return v == limite; }))
    ++v[distri(generador)];

const auto total = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), .0);

std::cout << "Total: " << total;

for (const auto& valor : v)
    std::cout << valor << '\t' << valor / total << '\n';
```

He obtenido este resultado:

> ```
> Total:    42949668382
> 4294966985    0.1000000
> 4294966361    0.1000000
> 4294966743    0.1000000
> 4294967068    0.1000000
> 4294966763    0.1000000
> 4294966783    0.1000000
> 4294966720    0.1000000
> 4294966776    0.1000000
> 4294967295    0.1000000
> 4294966888    0.1000000
> ```

Es más, si tu objetivo es obtener una distribución normal no necesitas aplicar una transformación: puedes generar números directamente con esa distribución:

```
constexpr unsigned valores = 10u;
constexpr unsigned limite = 0xffffffffu;

unsigned v[valores]{};

std::random_device device;
std::mt19937 generador(device());
std::normal_distribution<> distri(5, 1);
//   ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~          ^  ^
//            \                    \  \__ Desvío de la distribución.
//             \                    \
//              \                    \___ Media de la distribución
//               \
//                \___ Distribución normal

while (!std::any_of(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [limite](auto v) { return v == limite; }))
    ++v[static_cast<std::size_t>(distri(generador))];

const auto total = std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v), .0);

std::cout << "Total: " << total << '\n';

for (const auto& valor : v)
    std::cout << valor << '\t' << valor / total << '\n';
```

Con el que he obtenido este resultado:

> ```
> Total:    12582396805
> 397820    0.0000316
> 16573165  0.0013172
> 269252286 0.0213991
> 1709947726    0.1359000
> 4294925005    0.3413439
> 4294967295    0.3413473
> 1710067581    0.1359095
> 269270524 0.0214006
> 16599688  0.0013193
> 395715    0.0000314
> ```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>Es decir: la parte positiva de un número entero de 16 bits ½2<sup>16</sup> - 1

###### <sup>2</sup>Suele basarse en un generador lineal congruencial, con todas sus [desventajas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generador_lineal_congruencial#Ventajas_y_desventajas).