# ¿Problema con contador en ciclo anidado?

Tags: c++, bucle-for

Explico el problema: el funcionamiento consiste en lanzar mil valores al azar entre 1 y 100; luego almacenar en un contador los valores menores a 13.

Después repetir eso 10.000 veces (o sea tendremos 10.000 valores) finalmente almacenar esos 10.000 valores en un array e imprimir. Todo eso lo tengo listo. El problema es que no se como reiniciar el contador a 0, porque solo me imprime ceros en pantalla.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main(){
    int num, c; 
    int contador=0;
    srand(time(NULL));  
    int contadora[10000]={0};             //Declaracion del arreglo, de 10.000 valores por asignar.
 
    
    for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++){       //En este ciclo tengo problemas
        for(c =0 ; c <= 1000; c++){
            num = 1 + rand() % (101 - 1); //Nuestro rango, Número aleatorios entre 1 y 100.

            
            if (num <= 13 ){              //contabilizamos los valores menores a 13.
                contador = contador +1 ;
                
            } 
        }
        
         contadora[j]=contador;
         for(j=0; j<10000; j++){
            cout<<contadora[j]<<endl;
         }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que sacar el bucle que imprime los valores de `contadora` **fuera** del bucle que genera los números aleatorios ... lo que hace ahora es imprimir 10000 veces la lista de resultados, una vez por cada iteración:

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    for(int c = 0; c <= 1000; c++) {
        // ...
    }
}

for(int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
    cout << contadora[j] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Por completar la respuesta, también le falta la parte de reiniciar `contador` a cero, tras cada iteración. Eso podría ir antes del segundo for anidado, o después de `contadora[j] = contador;`

Comment: @ArianJM o podría declarar la variable contador dentro del primer bucle ... así no se le puede olvidar la inicialización porque entonces el programa te mostraría, al menos, un warning

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema está derivado de una mala estructuración del código, no hay una separación clara entre cada una de las tareas que quieres hacer:

1. Generar valores aleatorios.
2. Contar los que cumplen una condición.
3. Almacenar el recuento anterior.

Por esa mala separación de tareas, tu código es ineficiente y difícil de comprender lo que te lleva a cometer el [error mencionado por eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/537350/2742). Te aconsejo separar cada tarea para hacer más claro tu código, usar variables cuyo nombre sea auto-explicativo y [dejar de usar `rand`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/495695/2742):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

template <auto min, auto max>
int genera_entre()
{
    static std::random_device device;
    static std::mt19937 generador(device());
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribucion(min, max);

    return distribucion(generador);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int recuento = 10000;
    int valores[100]{};
    int menor_o_igual_a_13[recuento]{};

    // Por cada elemento de 'menor_o_igual_a_13'...
    for (auto &recuento : menor_o_igual_a_13)
    {
        // Genera numeros en 'valores' usando la funcion 'genera_entre<1, 100>'
        std::generate(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores), genera_entre<1, 100>);
        // Cuenta cuantos elementos generados cumplen la condicion 'valor <= 13'
        recuento = std::count_if(std::begin(valores), std::end(valores), [](int valor) { return valor <= 13; });
    }

    // Mostrar resultados
    for (int indice = 0; indice != recuento; ++indice)
        std::cout
            << "En el test " << (indice + 1)
            << " se contaron " << menor_o_igual_a_13[indice]
            << " numeros <= 13\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZNNj9owEIbPya@YUqlJBMsu5VAtBC5V1VOl3imKvM6QWkps5I/VSoi/Xjq2kxRaDs0l9mT8@pl5J/x4fOAtk83l8l5I3roaoRTKWI2s26Z/YprJWt1EWNsoLexPCqYWu2PLrI86q6ATcgZxxd62qZAWGpSoWYWSlPMiPaWJscwKDsbWq1VUr2p8FRwhvta3KZ1dPD8vP/VCtdJ5TMuL4q9MJ8VB6a6ia6taUCnixVmhZLmFYctpmwdKAqTzaaLROi1vE8arKOOchjI6JmTE50oai29HDT6ukTuqTcEGFk/0EJIPv7JWaTQ7iu1P5z7YoVS6UpVoHGsrVi2Wu@F4SEqTx0f4rjRwVjPAFrugTD3P/j2azefzNKF6IQ8N/zCSrO5cVKQJoXv9r6E2kK5DrQyghKyHzcAZbwe0DA5O@k5Adm1fuZj5IrcZKYWGx48W87B7wYZ61IsVs@gJyvoqdE/Nu@jBPnt6BtwxKsKM5ZvReEPfaNqImADJhVpExCAPJRmw9GRXjgQCrhzNgzj8N@Run48WFnCCfkKurlnD2VOfo2Pf/F/DNOUZ11oP2vviVYTHRGJ5Wg/rd5txatYwncZoMfSUcC2tk7KEyRdJbQCLxsIEKJD3ClNYFEMOGPTNsExTL0LWnTGL5/bjmcH9UM0PObn6EWiCz5fLL35oWWMuD8S04dPpR/Yb)</kbd>.